# String showing special characters as it was urlencoded

Tags: php, windows, macos, csv, encoding

I've got a site where the user can upload a csv file with some information and I read and save that information in the database. The problem is, the user sometimes report that the information he/she uploads appears with "strange characters" in the browser and I've checked and it was saved in the database the same way (with "strange characters). So I asked for the file he/she used and upload from my computer and everything went fine. The user uploaded from a Mac computer and I uploaded from a Windows computer. The server with the site is Windows.

Here's a print of the error the user describes:

[image: User print]

I can upload that same csv and that string stays ok. I noticed the "strange characters" are codes for url's. For example the space is replaced by %20 in the print. But this string comes from a csv file that apparently is ok. And as I can't reproduce the error it's hard to understand what could be happening. But all seems to be some kind of encoding problem between Mac-Windows. Do you ever got this king of problem?

EDIT:

Here's the code that handles the csv file:

```
            while ($valor = fgetcsv ($handle, filesize($T2), ";")){
                for ($i=0;$i<$conta;$i++){
                    $cv=$data[$i];
                    $row[$cv]=trim($valor[$i]); 
                }

                if ($row['Ano']==$sql_Documento['Ano'] && $sql_Documento['NumDocumento']==$row['Numero']){    
                    $count++;
                    $campos = array();
                    $campos['IdDocumento'] = $sql_Documento[IdDocumento];
                    $campos['Sociedade'] = mssql_escape_string($row['Sociedade']); //this is the field that gives me problems
                    $campos['DocumentoId'] = $sql_Documento[DocumentoId];
                    $campos['page_dr'] = $row['Pagdr'];
                    $campos['page_file'] = $row['Pagpdf'];
                    $DocumentoId = insertNewRecord("DocSoc",$campos);
                }              

            }
```

The mssql_escape_string is this function:

```
    function mssql_escape_string($data) {
        if ( !isset($data) or empty($data) ) return '';
        if ( is_numeric($data) ) return $data;

        $non_displayables = array(
            '/%0[0-8bcef]/',            // url encoded 00-08, 11, 12, 14, 15
            '/%1[0-9a-f]/',             // url encoded 16-31
            '/[\x00-\x08]/',            // 00-08
            '/\x0b/',                   // 11
            '/\x0c/',                   // 12
            '/[\x0e-\x1f]/'             // 14-31
        );
        foreach ( $non_displayables as $regex )
            $data = preg_replace( $regex, '', $data );
        $data = str_replace("'", "''", $data );
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: There seems to be some proper encoding and/or decoding missing at server and/or client.

Comment: Try to apply the `urldecode()` on to those columns values. Can you show us a part of your code please.

Comment: Those characters won't show up magically in your database. Either the user entered them exactly that way (that can happen if you copy a URL from the browser location bar) or you have PHP code that explicitly encodes them.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález but if the user did something like that wouldn't it show in the csv file? It's weird that I have the exact same file (the user send me) and I've upload with no problems.